# Googlescript code with namedvalues not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to send an automatic email to my students with feedback on the coursework.  I have developed a google form with the marking scheme where I enter the student number, but the script doesn't read the named values method.

I have tried to do one by one student numbers and the rest of the code it works.

The code is as follows:

```
    function sendNotification(e){
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var message = "";
    var headers =s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    message += "This automated email includes the marks and feedback for    
    your Main report Assignment.\n\n";

    var studentNumber = e.namedValues[headers[3]].toString();   
    Logger.log("column 3: " + studentNumber);

    message += "Student Number: " + studentNumber + "\n\n";

    var recipients = studentNumber + "@email.com";
    var subject = "Test Email";

    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, message);
    }
```

I want to be able to gather the student email from the google form, that is already saved in column 3 of the spreadsheet that is attached to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my answer is a little rushed as I am literally leaving. (As is my code.) Normally don't do this, but since you are a teacher willing to make an exception.

Hope the below code helps. (This is how I would accomplish the task you are trying to do.)

```
function helpingTheTeacher() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR_SHEET_NAME_HERE");

  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

  var timeStamp = values[i][0];
  var studentName = values[i][1];
  var studentNumber = values[i][2];
  var studentGrade = values[i][3];


  var message = "Hi " +studentName + " your grade is " +studentGrade + "."

  var email = studentNumber + "@email.com";

  var subject = "ALERT: MESSAGE FROM TEACHER!!!";

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message)

  }//END OF FOR LOOP
  }//END OF FUNCTION
```